# How to get email address of shared folder user in Dropbox using Dropbox API v2 C#

Tags: api, sdk, dropbox

I want to list down the list of emailID's of the users with whom an Dropbox folder is shared. I am using Dropbox API v2 SDK (C#) to perform the action. I am able to get the count of users and their Basic Account Information (user name), but not able to get their Full Account Information (I need Email address of that user).

I am referring to the below links:
http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/T_Dropbox_Api_Users_FullAccount.htm

I am able to get the details via direct get call to api
GET https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/shared_folders/ in Google Postman.

Can you please help me in achieving this via Dropbox API v2 SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox API v2 doesn't currently return the email addresses for members of shared folders, but we'll consider this a feature request.

Comment: Thanks Greg for confirming on this. Surely we would like to have this feature in API SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in vanilla JS http without using a library:

1) use "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/list_mountable_folders" to obtain the list of mountable folders and their "**shared_folder_id**".

2) for each folder: use "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/list_folder_members" to obtain the list of the members of the folder and their "**account_id**"

3) for each member: use "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_account" to obtain the account data with the "name", "display_name", "**email**", etc.